# SQL Server: interpreting 'y' as BIT value

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

In C, when you compared true/false value to 1/0, it worked very well.

I would want the similar possibility with SQL Server - when I have a `bit` column, I would like to compare `myBitField = 'y'` / `myBitField = 'n'`

Is there anything I can do about that? Maybe change some SQL interpreter settings or something?

**Example** of what I would like to do:

```
select * from
(
   select CAST(1 AS BIT) as result
) as main
where main.result = 'y'
```

Currently, it throws an error, and I would like it to return 1/true/'y', whatever, but I would like it to be able to make that comparison.

Comment: Not sure I understand corectly but in SQL if you declare myBitField as bit it will be 0 for false and 1 for true.

Comment: @CiucaS: Yes, and I would like to compare this bit field to 'y'/'n'.

Comment: In T-SQL, the `bit` datatype has two possible values - 0 being false, 1 being true - and it can be NULL. Nothing else. No settings available to change this. You'll have to get used to 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want to do it for some yes/no thing. But this is generally a wrong concept, your application which is accessing the SQL Server should interpret y as a 1 and n as a 0 and afterwards set the correct parameters for the query. You should not (actually I'm temped to write "must not") do this in SQL Server, that's what you have a business logic for.

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of that, but I am currently in the process of migrating my company's old erp system into a new one, and am considering my options regarding char(1)/bit issue. ;)

Comment: Ok, I can understand the interest for a legacy system in order to change it only once, but I'll keep my answer standing in case someone with a terrible application design will find this question  ;)

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, BIT and CHAR / VARCHAR are entirely different datatypes. But if you want to cast them during the select, you can use CASE expression like so:

```
-- Reading string as BIT
SELECT CAST(CASE RESULT WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 WHEN 'N' THEN 0 ELSE NULL END AS BIT) RESULT

-- Reading BIT as string
SELECT CAST(CASE RESULT WHEN 1 THEN 'Y' WHEN 0 THEN 'N' ELSE NULL END AS CHAR(1)) RESULT
```

And that's about as far as your options go here, far as I can understand. :)